# WSO2 analytics 2.0.0 (with API manager 2.0.0) - statistic data wrong - numbers always increasing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed WSO2AM-2.0.0 and WSO2AM-analytics-2.0.0. 
When I tested statistic data for "API usage per application" I notice some strange number during some period of time.
Example: I tested CalculatorAPI, made 5 request and then check data in statistics.
At first everything was fine, I see 5 request. But then after cca. 10 minutes there is 15 requests, after 1 hour 50 requests, after few days more then 1000 requests and always increasing. I notice that data increasing incrementally after some period of time (maybe some scheduler send data every few minutes) and because of that I have huge numbers in statistics.

Why this numbers always increasing?
Is this some mistake during setup of application or some bug in application?

I notice that increasing last only for that day, next day everything is reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers are generated by spark queries executed every 5 minutes in DAS. For what you say, the spark query evaluates all the data sent by API Manager in every execution, I mean, it's not ignoring already processed data.
Try with another number of requests. If it increases this number every 5 minutes, you can confirm the issue.

You can search the script and try to change it; spark queries are not easy to understand, but it can be done :)

The reason it gets set to 0 every day is because some purge data process is being launched in DAS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I try with different number of requests and its same, always increasing for that number. This is issue only with Wso2 Analytics, if I use Wso2DAS then numbers are fine, but I don't have other features of Wso2 analytics. I am not sure if this is bug in Analytics or something else.